# Is there any way to imlement a rotating proxy based HttpClient in reactor netty?

Tags: java, proxy, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

As per the available examples and documentation, it seems that the way to use a proxy with an http-client is like so:

```
HttpClient.create()
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 2_000)
        .doOnConnected(connection ->
                connection
                        .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(2_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                        .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(2_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
        .proxy(proxy -> proxy
                .type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
                .host((${host})
                .port(${port})
                .build()));
```

It seems like in this setup, once initialized, it is not possible to change the host of the proxy. So, how would one go about implementing a rotating proxy? like

It is possible to do it apache httpclient4 where one can configure a different proxy per request using RequestConfig in the following manner:

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
.setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, port, "https"))
.build();
```

However, httpclient4 is a blocking client library and i couldn't find any reactive alternative that can work with WebClient in Spring Boot

Comment: Do you have many proxy configurations or just a few? If there are not many for the moment you can have several HttpClients as a solution as such feature similar to httpclient4 is not available.

Comment: Thank you, I made separate clients for each proxy